# Enhanced Explorer for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-explorer, desktop-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacement for Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/90/replacement-for-windows-explorer)

Is there a better explorer for Windows XP with [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror)-like features (like dual panes), etc. Specially an enhanced integrated search option like in Vista? There are different products which cumulatively present something similar like [xplorer2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xplorer%C2%B2), [Google Desktop Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop) or [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/). But what about one integrated product?

Comment: Duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/90 and http://superuser.com/questions/26777

Answer (score 4):

## [UltraExplorer](http://download.cnet.com/UltraExplorer/3000-2248_4-10702384.html)

[image]

or

## [NexusFile](http://xiles.net/downloads/#NexusFile)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [SpeedCommander](http://www.speedproject.de/enu/speedcommander/index.html) (dual pane, excellent archiver, lots of features including search, batch rename etc.). Although for search/replace operations, I prefer [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using good old [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com) for as long as I can remember, ever since Win95 I think. Advanced search, two multi-tabbed panes, reads into archives, functions as an FTP client, has a multi-rename tool, a decent internal viewer, adjustable display... the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/) over the years and I think it's personally one of the best replacements and most customizable replacements available. Unfortunately, it's not free. The screenshot shows it in Vista, but it is XP compatible.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: +1 My favourite as well, been using it forever, it's not too expensive for what it does when you get addicted ^^

Comment: I tend to get frustrated when I end up on another machine and double-clicking on the desktop doesn't open a lister.

Answer (score 0):

[Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=freeware/Q-Dir) is very good. Very easy to configure the panes according to how your files are distributed. And it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[Freecommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) is supposed to be a free alternative to Total Commander, it lacks quite alot of features but it might be features your not interested in. At the very least it's worth looking at.

I myself however cannot get used to the likes of Total Commander so I'm sticking with good old Explorer :)